# Java Hibernate JOIN with a inner Criteria throws no session or session was closed

Tags: java, hibernate

i have written a small piece of code like this. i need all the students and they phones in a one to many relationship.

```
public ArrayList<Student>getListOfStudents()
{        
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();        
    Criteria like = session.createCriteria(Student.class).setFetchMode("phone",FetchMode.JOIN).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    prepareForSelect(like);//some filtering       
    like.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));        
    ArrayList<Student> results = new ArrayList<Student>(like.list());
    session.close();
    return results;
}
```

this is working very good but i need to tweak it because i need to implement the same criteria filtering in phone as well i have redesign my snippet to something like this.

```
public ArrayList<Student>getListOfStudents()
{        
    Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();        
    Criteria like = session.createCriteria(Student.class).setFetchMode("phone",FetchMode.JOIN).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    prepareForSelect(like);//some filtering       
    Criteria innerCriteria = like.createCriteria("phone");
    prepareForSelect(innerCriteria);//same filtering but in phone now..
    like.addOrder(Order.asc("c01"));        
    ArrayList<Student> results = new ArrayList<Student>(like.list());
    session.close();
    return results;
}
```

but hibernate has changed from left outer join to a inner join and when i run the data in the same methods the before code was running i can see a error is throw.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.generic.model.Student.phone, no session or session was closed.
```

my question is what i am doing wrong how can i apply the filters and get the joins correctly thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that the phones of a student are not eagerly fetched. And since you are closing the session, when you are try to access the phones you are getting `LazyInitializationException`.

But you are asking yourself I had set the fetch mode to eager by using `setFetchMode("phone",FetchMode.JOIN)` and it was working just fine. The thing is, there is a bug in Hibernate which disables eager fetching when you add an inner query to a criteria. It is still open. See here:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3524

And if you have time you can take a look at here:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944439

If you do, make sure you read the second page, it gets funnier.

So my suggestion is to make the fetch eager at the class level, by using `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` or switch to CriteriaBuilder (JPA).

Comment: this is still present in the latest hibernate version??

Comment: I checked with Hibernate 4.1.9. But if it is possible you may want to switch to Hibernate JPA (using CriteriaBuilder). I read this bug is not present in that implementation.

Comment: unfortunately is not on me switch to it.

Comment: i am making some progress but still not everything is OK. please take a lot a my issue. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651866/hibernate-criteria-alias-to-entity-map-to-arraylist-student-missing